# In the one of my controller and also a service class I have a duplicate lines of code what is the best practice to refactor them

Tags: java, spring-mvc, service, controller

I'm beginner in java and I'm writing cash-in and cash-out functionalities in the digital wallet. I don't know how can I fix these type of duplication. This is my controller class that just their URL and service call are different

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wallet_transaction")
public class WalletTransactionController {


    @PutMapping("/cash-in/{walletId}")
    void cashIn(@PathVariable String walletId,
                @RequestBody @Valid WalletTransactionRequest walletTransactionRequest) throws WalletInactiveException {
        WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto = walletTransactionMapper
                                                    .walletTrRequestToWalletTrDto(walletTransactionRequest);
        walletTransactionService.chashIn(walletId, walletTransactionDto);
    }

    @PutMapping("/cash-out/{walletId}")
    void cashOut(@PathVariable String walletId,
                 @RequestBody @Valid WalletTransactionRequest walletTransactionRequest) throws WalletInactiveException, InsufficientBalanceException {
        WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto = walletTransactionMapper
                .walletTrRequestToWalletTrDto(walletTransactionRequest);
        walletTransactionService.cashOut(walletId, walletTransactionDto);
    }
```

also my service class is like below. the main functionality of them are same. just inner method invocation are different

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void chashIn(String walletId, WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto) throws WalletInactiveException {
    WalletTransaction walletTransaction = walletTransactionMapper
                                            .walletTransactionDtoToWalletTransaction(walletTransactionDto);
    Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findWalletByWalletId(walletId);
    String iban = wallet.getUser().getIban();

    if(wallet.getStatus().equals(WalletStatus.ACTIVE)){
        walletTransaction.setWallet(wallet);
        walletTransaction.setWalletTransactionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        walletTransaction.setTransactionType(TransactionType.CASH_IN);
        debitTransactionService.withdraw(walletTransaction, iban);
        walletTransactionRepository.save(walletTransaction);
    }else {
        throw new WalletInactiveException(wallet.getName() +"is inactive so you cannot do any transaction." +
                " to activate it use the \"enable wallet\" api :>");
    }
    walletService.updateBalance(walletId, (double)walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount(),
                                    walletTransaction.getTransactionType());
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void cashOut(String walletId, WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto)
        throws WalletInactiveException, InsufficientBalanceException {

    WalletTransaction walletTransaction = walletTransactionMapper
            .walletTransactionDtoToWalletTransaction(walletTransactionDto);
    Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findWalletByWalletId(walletId);
    String iban = wallet.getUser().getIban();

    if(wallet.getStatus().equals(WalletStatus.ACTIVE)){
        if(walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount()<= wallet.getBalance()){
            walletTransaction.setWallet(wallet);
            walletTransaction.setWalletTransactionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            walletTransaction.setTransactionType(TransactionType.CASH_OUT);
            debitTransactionService.deposit(walletTransaction, iban);
            walletTransactionRepository.save(walletTransaction);
        }else{
            throw new InsufficientBalanceException("the balance of "+wallet.getName() +
                    " wallet is not sufficient. you can increase the wallet balance by" +
                    "using \"cash in\" api");
        }
    }else{
        throw new WalletInactiveException(wallet.getName() +" wallet is inactive so you cannot do any transaction." +
                " to activate it, use the \"enable wallet\" api :>");
    }

    walletService.updateBalance(walletId, (double)walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount(),
            walletTransaction.getTransactionType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While both methods cashOut and cashIn look very similar from first glance - it is more important that functionally they actually are expected to perform opposite actions.

It is a good practice to extract similar code blocks in functionalities that are expected to perform same thing. However, in case when expected flows are opposite - it is usually more useful to let those flows be separate - even with cost of introduction of duplication. Having flows as separate allows to make modifications easily in each flow without even a possibility to affect another flow. And in long term it would lead to code that is easier to maintain.

However, if some minor code blocks do really do same thing (as additional population of walletTransaction in your example) - such parts could be extracted into some common method. This is because in both flows walletTransaction needs to be properly populated.

So, summing up, I'd leave code as is - apart from 2 minor similar code extractions:

1 - common logic of wallet transaction update

```
private void updateWalletTransaction(WalletTransaction walletTransaction, Wallet wallet, TransactionType transactionType) {
    walletTransaction.setWallet(wallet);
    walletTransaction.setWalletTransactionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    walletTransaction.setTransactionType(TransactionType.CASH_OUT);
}
```

And call it in both methods as

```
updateWalletTransaction(walletTransaction, wallet, TransactionType.CASH_IN);
```

or

```
updateWalletTransaction(walletTransaction, wallet, TransactionType.CASH_OUT);
```

2 - common logic of checking that wallet is in ACTIVE status

```
private void checkWalletIsActive(Wallet wallet) {
    if (wallet.getStatus() != WalletStatus.ACTIVE) {
        throw new WalletInactiveException(wallet.getName() +"is inactive so you cannot do any transaction." +
                " to activate it use the \"enable wallet\" api :>");
    }
}
```

So resulting methods would look smth like:

```
public void cashIn(String walletId, WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto) throws WalletInactiveException {
    WalletTransaction walletTransaction = walletTransactionMapper
                                        .walletTransactionDtoToWalletTransaction(walletTransactionDto);
    Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findWalletByWalletId(walletId);
    String iban = wallet.getUser().getIban();

    checkWalletIsActive(wallet);
    updateWalletTransaction(walletTransaction, wallet, TransactionType.CASH_IN);
    debitTransactionService.withdraw(walletTransaction, iban);
    walletTransactionRepository.save(walletTransaction);

    walletService.updateBalance(walletId, (double)walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount(),
                                walletTransaction.getTransactionType());
}
```

and

```
public void cashOut(String walletId, WalletTransactionDto walletTransactionDto)
        throws WalletInactiveException, InsufficientBalanceException {
    WalletTransaction walletTransaction = walletTransactionMapper
                                        .walletTransactionDtoToWalletTransaction(walletTransactionDto);
    Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findWalletByWalletId(walletId);
    String iban = wallet.getUser().getIban();

    checkWalletIsActive(wallet);
    if (walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount() <= wallet.getBalance()) {
            updateWalletTransaction(walletTransaction, wallet, TransactionType.CASH_OUT);
            debitTransactionService.deposit(walletTransaction, iban);
            walletTransactionRepository.save(walletTransaction);
    } else {
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException("the balance of "+wallet.getName() +
                " wallet is not sufficient. you can increase the wallet balance by" +
                "using \"cash in\" api");
    }
    walletService.updateBalance(walletId, (double)walletTransaction.getTransactionAmount(),
        walletTransaction.getTransactionType());
}
```